# Deleting last values in array (using Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numbers

I have an `Array[0]` with `len(Array[0]) = 40`
I want to delete the last 3 values in this array.

```
np.delete(Array[0],[36,39])
```

Works as it should. However,

```
np.delete(Array[0],[len(Array[0])-4,len(Array[0])-1])
```

Deletes only the last number (instead of the last 3).

```
np.delete(Array[0],[-3,-1])
```

Doesn't do anything and gives me the warning:
**main**:1: FutureWarning: in the future negative indices will not be ignored by `numpy.delete`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Simply slice : `Array[0][:-3]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `range(37, 40)` along with `axis` keyword argument to delete the last three columns. Here is a contrived example:

```
In [88]: arr = np.random.random_sample((3, 10))
In [89]: arr.shape
Out[89]: (3, 10)

In [90]: new_arr = np.delete(arr, range(7, 10), axis=1)

In [91]: new_arr.shape
Out[91]: (3, 7)
```

Please note that [**`numpy.delete()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) would return a new sub-array. If you're wary of memory requirements, you should [slice as Divakar suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549714/deleting-last-values-in-array-using-numpy#comment97800898_55549714).

```
sliced_arr = Array[0][:-3]
```

But then you've to be careful when you modify the sliced array since that's a view of the original array.